# How to properly use SRC_DIRS parameter in idf_component_register function in esp-idf?

Tags: cmake, esp32, platformio, esp-idf

I'm new to ESP-IDF and Platformio.

I want to add my source files in CMakeLists.txt by folders, not one by one as files. This should be done by SRC_DIRS but it doesn't work for me. How can I get it done?

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't work for me". Also, please consider adding your code snippets as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: @Tarmo The linker reports functions declared in files in "uart" folder as undefined, so the linker doesn't see these declaration. 'c:/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\esp32dev\src\main.o:(.literal.app_main+0x14): undefined reference to `uartTask(void*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\firmware.elf] Error 1'

Comment: @Tarmo I posted a question as screenshot so that one can see projects' structure.

Comment: OK, the linker can't find objects for the source in directory "uart". But does the compiler compile them? Also, you've renamed the "main" component to "src", which is OK but you have to perform a [few extra steps](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#renaming-main-component) in the top level CMakeLists.txt when doing that. Did you? Finally, there are [gotchas](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#file-globbing-incremental-builds) when globbing. Run `idf.py reconfigure` before building.

Comment: @Tarmo a) It doesn't compile the source in uart folder. b) I didn't rename the "main" to "src", it was imported as example project from Platformio (it was espidf-arduino-blink example). The only thing I renamed was Blink.cpp, which is now main.cpp. But "src/" name of the folder was already there, when I imported it. So no, I didn't do those steps and I'm not sure that I should.

Comment: Platformio uses the ESP IDF build system (although they seem to have made some minor modifications to the default CMake project) so the document that I've pointed to is your authoritative source of information. Read it, figure out what you're missing. Or, alternatively, specify the individual source files one by one.

Comment: @Tarmo The "one by one" does work, but you can imagine that is not acceptable, cause, potentially, I can have dozens of classes and, hence, dozens of source files. I read the documentation and wasn't able to figure it out, that's why I posted it here. The problem is nowhere in example projects on internet or github anyone uses this directive, so there is no reference for me, but I can't believe everyone just adds their source files one by one.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's the most deterministic description of your project for CMake and mostly a one-time effort. I have a project with 37 cpp files listed in `SRCS` and I don't really think about it.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured it out. In the [docs](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#cmake-component-register)

> idf_component_register([[SRCS src1 src2 ...] | [[SRC_DIRS dir1 dir2
> ...] [EXCLUDE_SRCS src1 src2 ...]]

notice the "OR" bar between SRCS and SRC_DIRS. This made me think that I can either use either SRCS or SRC_DIRS, but not both at the same time. So following works

> idf_component_register(SRC_DIRS "." "uart")

Notice, however, as @Tarmo noticed, that you have to run reconfigure or clean build each time you add a new source.